# How many snakes there can be in the "snakes and ladders" game?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, board-games

How to calculate the maximum allowed number of snakes in the game of ["snakes and ladders"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snakes_and_Ladders) from mathematical/algorithmic point of view assuming that there is a nxn board?

UPD: My thoughts are simple, but they might be incorrect:
I suppose once any two fields on the board cannot be involved twice forming a snake it means that in nxn board there can be nxn/2 snakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume any given square can be the head or tail (but not both) of at most one snake then clearly an upper limit on the number of snakes on a $n \times n$ board is $\frac {n^2} 2$. For a $m \times n$ board we can generalise this to $\frac {mn} 2$. And we can reach this upper limit if either $m$ or $n$ is even. What happens if $m$ and $n$ are both odd ?